# How to get Data from an activity from other activity ..in android..?

Tags: android

I am very new to android development and I am facing problem while writing code for a contact book. My question is :

I have Two `activity` class (`main_activity` and `addcontact_activity`) ,In `main_activity` ----one `button`,`listview` and One `EditText`, if I click on `button` then it redirects to second activity and In second activity ---three `editText`(for name,phone number and email) and two `button`s(save and clear)

In first activity everything fine but when I clicked on save `button` from second activity then it links to `Main_activity` but the data sent from second activity to first activity it doesn't show in `main_activity` so please help!

**Code of `Main_activity`**:

```
EditText t;
Button b;
ListView lv;
ArrayList <String> al;
ArrayAdapter<String> ad;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    t=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);



    al=new ArrayList<String>();
    ad=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,al);
    lv.setAdapter(ad);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(v.getId()==R.id.button1){
        Intent link = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),addcontact.class);
        startActivity(link);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    Intent Info = getIntent();
    al.add(Info.getStringExtra("name").toString());
    ad.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

}

**code for `addContact_activity`**:

```
TextView name,phone,email;
Button save, reset;
EditText n,p,e;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addcon);

    name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    phone=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    email=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    reset=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    n=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    p=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v.getId()==R.id.save){
        Intent send = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        send.putExtra("name", n.getText().toString());
        startActivity(send);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please follow this link:-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you are sending the data to another `activity` using `Intent`, and correctly so by:

```
 Intent send = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            send.putExtra("name", n.getText().toString());
            startActivity(send);
```

Now, in order to retrieve the data, you need to get it from `Intent` in `MainActivity`, by:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
```

put that in `onCreate()` of `MainActivity`.

Insert a null check before reading your data...for the `Intent` so it doesn't throw a NPE.
Something like:

```
if(getIntent()!=null || getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
```

Read more for `Intents` on:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
[What is an Intent in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578051/what-is-intent-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Do below codes inside `OnCreate()`

```
Intent Info = getIntent();
al.add(Info.getStringExtra("name").toString());
ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    t=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);



    al=new ArrayList<String>();
    ad=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,al);
    lv.setAdapter(ad);
    Intent Info = getIntent();
    if(Info.hasExtra("name")){
      al.add(Info.getStringExtra("name").toString());
      ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ..but when I write your code into the OnCreate() in  Main activity it gives an error because at first time when main activity runs it does not get any Intent information so that why this code not run..!!!!!

Comment: @user3462608 see my edited code. I used `if(Info.hasExtra("name"))` condition try it.

Answer (score 0):

use getInent().getExtras() to get the bundle.
or getIntent().getExtra();

Answer (score 0):

add this code on onResume() instead of on pause

```
Intent Info = getIntent();
    al.add(Info.getStringExtra("name").toString());
    ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
```