# Swapping screens with button. Crashes

Tags: java, android, button

I have been messing around with this for a few days now and have the code identical to that in the tutorial and yet it still doesn't want to work, Why?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mdpmk1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScanScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);   

            }

        });

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Screen One......"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scan"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me to another screen" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ScanScreen.java

```
package com.example.mdpmk1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ScanScreen extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scan_screen);
    }

}
```

scan_screen.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="You have done it!!"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.firstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Any help would be lovely, This has relay been annoying me and i know that it is probably a simple mistake.

Comment: what's the error? is your `ScanScreen` activity defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Do you have your `ScanScreen` Activity listed in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: I don't know if i have or haven't defined the ScanScreen, I followed a tutorial and this is what the code ended looking like, That is every line of code that i have on the app

Comment: post code of your androidmanifest.xml also..

Comment: Updated, Now including the AndroidMainfest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following in your [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

```
<activity android:name=".ScanScreen" />
```

within `application` like so:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ScanScreen" />
</application>
```

Here is a quote from the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) on what the `activity` tags are for:

> Declares an activity (an Activity subclass) that implements part of
>   the application's visual user interface. All activities must be
>   represented by  elements in the manifest file. Any that are
>   not declared there will not be seen by the system and will never be
>   run.

That last sentence is important.

Answer (score 0):

In your case writing `<activity android:name=".ScanScreen" />` above `</application>` will solve your problem.
Whenever you need to use any activity in android you have to mention it in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Just giving answer to you won't help you.
You should first read on below links to understand what is intent and intent-filters used for.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html
[What is an Intent in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578051/what-is-intent-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Your app crashes because your not setting or registered the activity in manifest.You haven't added the `ScanScreen` Activity in your manifest file.
Just add the following to your  AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<activity android:name=".ScanScreen" />
```

within your application tag like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ScanScreen" />
</application>
```