# External Links to load OUTSIDE of Ionic / Cordova app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on a Ionic / Cordova app where I load feeds and news that sometimes contain external links. I need to load those external links outside of the app, not in the InAppBrowser but in the phone browser.

Is it possible to do this as a default behavior on all links?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? can you edit your question and provide some code ?

Comment: I usually open external links with window.open and targer system, in this case I need to do it dynamically on every link embedded in the feed i load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For external links you have to use the [inAppbrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) Plugin.For your reqiurment after including the plugin to open in phone browser. use the code

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_system', 'location=yes');

/*
_self: Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.
_blank: Opens in the InAppBrowser.
_system: Opens in the system's web browser.
*/
```

Comment: thanks but my links are embedded in the feeds I load with the app, I need a filter or something to transform every link in a window.open('http://apache.org', '_system', 'location=yes');

Comment: I had a problem where this didn't work - it was because i had removed "cordova.js" white testing in the browser :i.... Don't do the same mistake guys :)

Answer (score 7):

In order to open URL using the corresponding system  application you need the [whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist). If your project is based on the scaffolded demo program, it should already be installed. If not (or simply to ensure that) :

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Once the plug-in is installed, you will have to specify the [intend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578051/what-is-intent-in-android) you want to open from your application. In your config.xml, add:

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
...
```

Given the above rules, all URI stating with one of the specified protocols (http, https, tel, sms, mailto, ...) will be open using the corresponding system application. Of course, you can be much more specific by replacing the `*` wildcards by actual values.

See [this article](http://devgirl.org/2015/04/24/apache-cordova-newsflash/) for additional details.

Comment: Thank you, that is perfectly what I needed for opening a external URL with the system browser without additional plugin.

Comment: There's no single answer as of today on the topic which could be as simple as this answer is.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install following plugin

```
 > ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Inside **index.html**

```
<div class="list">
    <a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://google.com', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
       Open Browser
    </a>    
</div>
```

For more info about this plugin visit the [plugin page](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/inappbrowser/inappbrowser.html).