# Cordova Wrapper App Where Internal Links Load In App, External Links Load In Browser

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a simple [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) wrapper app which points to an external webpage, without defining any of its own views.

I would like *all internal links from that domain to be loaded inside the app*, but *all external links (http://twitter.com, etc) to be loaded in the system browser*, so the pages have Back / Forward functionality.

In a normal app with views, I could set `target='_system'` to load links in the default browser, or use the [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) to explicitly open links in a web browser view. Unfortunately in this case I don't have the ability to edit the server side code, so need a solution that works within the app.

If I define the `config.xml` as such, then both internal and external links are loaded in app.

```
<content src="http://example.com/" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

If I define the `config.xml` with `allow-intent`, then internal and external links are opened in the system browser.

```
<content src="http://example.com/" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

[Others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29430835/385730) have [suggested](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Jul/02/External-Links-in-Cordova-for-iOS#HandlingTargetLinks) using custom javascript to override the `target` to `_system`, however since I don't have my own views I can't really do that.

Is it possible to define `allow-intent` for the [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) in such a way to include *all URLs that are not the internal domain*?

Or will I need to somehow override `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` in `MainViewController` and then call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, after some experimenting and suggestions from [Hayyaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3846593/hayyaan-ahmad), I was able to come up with combination of `allow-navigation` and `allow-intent` which served my purpose.

```
<content src="https://example.com/" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="about:*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://example.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*.example.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*.facebook.com/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

Now *all internal links from the website domain are loaded in the app*, while *external links are loaded in the system browser*.

Note, I included `<allow-navigation href="https://*.facebook.com/*" />` to allow loading of Facebook libraries otherwise I received an error.

```
ERROR Internal navigation rejected - 
<allow-navigation> not set for url='https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?
```

And also included `<allow-navigation href="about:*" />` to avoid an error for `about:blank`.

```
ERROR Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='about:blank'
```

Hopefully this helps someone else with the same problem *:)*

Comment: how do you achieve this?some abc.example.com to be navigated within the webview and xyz.example.com in external browser!