# Apache Cordova allow-navigation overridden by allow-intent

Tags: android, ios, cordova, whitelist, apache-cordova

We want every link on the app to be able to be opened in the external browser on the system, with the exception of a selection of hostnames.

We tried putting `<allow-navigation href="*.hostname.com/*"/>` , but this gets overridden when you use `<allow-intent href="http://*/*" /> and  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"` as the intent tags for all the other links in the app.

The expected result would be our hostnames being opened within the app, but they open on the external browser instead.

I've tried looking at all the recent documentation and help available on the net, but could not find an answer to my solution. Hope you guys know.

Edit: forgot to mention we run the latest cordova CLI and the latest whitelist plugin with the inappbrowser plugin.

Sincerely,

Daniel

Comment: where do you see this issue? on iOS? android? both? On cordova-ios 4.1.1 this should be fixed

Comment: @Thrinaria suggest you to have a look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127660/cordova-wrapper-app-where-internal-links-load-in-app-external-links-load-in-bro who dealt a similar issue

Comment: @jcesarmobile 6.1 both android and ios.

Comment: @Gandhi Yea I've seen this, and tried this, but it still got overridden.

Comment: I was wrong, it wasn't fixed on cordova-ios 4.1.1, it was fixed on 4.2.0. See my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866341/cordova-internal-hyperlinks-always-open-in-safari/38008662#38008662

Comment: solved? how do you achieve this?some abc.example.com to be navigated within the webview and xyz.example.com in external browser!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `<allow-*`> tags to this:

```
<allow-intent href="*.hostname.com/*"
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*"
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*"
<allow-access href="https://*/*"
<allow-access href="http://*/*"
```

The `<allow-navigation>` tag is for controlling urls the Cordova webview itself can be navigated to.

Look at this [article](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md) for a better understanding on Cordova's Whitelist.

Comment: allow-access should just be i.e. <access origin="*" />

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do it manually. You can use [inApp Browser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) plugin to achieve this.

1. Check the link is internal/external (By checking the hyperlink contains your hostname contains or not)
2. If it is external call the system's browser and open the link
   `cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://external-domain.name', '_system', 'location=yes');`
3. If it is internal open the link inside [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)
   `cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://yourdomain.name', '_blank', 'location=yes');`

You can ignore 3rd step if you don't need it.

Full code:

```
$(document).on("click","a",function(e){        
      var hrefs = $(this).attr("href");        

      if(hrefs.indexOf("yourdomain") > -1) {
          //Open link inside inAppBrowser   
          cordova.InAppBrowser.open(hrefs, '_blank', 'location=yes');
          e.preventDefault();//To prevent default click
       } 
      else {
           //Open link inside system browser
           cordova.InAppBrowser.open(hrefs, '_system', 'location=yes');
           e.preventDefault();//To prevent default click
       }
})
```