# Use of xyz.class in the initialization of Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Sorry if this question is a duplicate. i searched the web but didn't get anywhere. And i don't know how to ask this question.
Here's the Question.

```
public class CrimeActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_CRIME_ID =
        "com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.crime_id";
public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, UUID crimeId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, CrimeActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID, crimeId);
    return intent;
}

@Override
protected Fragment createFragment() {
    return new CrimeFragment();
}
```

In this code when intent is initialized the 2nd argument is CrimeActivity.class . What is CrimeActivity.class, how is it used.?
Can someone please help.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanx.

Comment: You searched and didn't find it? Know Android documentation? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E)

Comment: On SO here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578051/what-is-intent-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using intents, the second parameter, which is in your case, the `CrimeActivity.class`, should be the java activity class that will be fired up when you call `startActivity(intent);`

Let's just say you're running your application. By default, the first activity to be fired up is the `MainActivity.class`. Somewhere within that class, if you'll declare that intent and call `startActivity(intent)`, then it will fire up another page.

Comment: so what activity would it start?

Comment: @HimanshuDabas CrimeActivity will be called.

Comment: And what about the Context that it receives as the 1st argument.What is it used for?