# how to open another activity in android using a button without codding

Tags: android, eclipse, button, android-intent, android-activity

how can I order a button in an activity to open another activity not by writing codes and only by using properties menu or right-clicking on the button(pointed in the picture)[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni5Rm.png).
also I create a new activity(.java file) in src file.
Is it possible or I must write codes?

Comment: You will have to write code

Comment: its not possible.

Comment: You need this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578051/what-is-an-intent-in-android

Answer (score 0):

For calling other activity you need to write code i.e. Intent like this you can call another activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,anotherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must. But its 1 line of code only. Add this to your button's onClick

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityToOpen.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `layout`  xml file inside button write  attribute `android:onClick`

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MyButton"
    android:onClick="YourMethodName" />
```

and inside Activity

```
public void YourMethodName(View v) {
// ButtonClickAction
 }
```

and this will call the method when button is clicked

how ever i would recommend to use Intent

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code, there is no escaping that. For opening another activity after clicking a button add the following on the OnClickListener of the button:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
   }
});
```

Remember to add the next activity within your AndroidManifest.xml file as follows or the activity won't run:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityB"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.BlackActionBar" />
```