# How do i make an intent to go to another activity from a clickable Textview?(Android Studios)

Tags: android, android-studio

i am a completely new user to Android Studios so pardon me. I'm here to find out how to  create an intent to start a new activity, from a clickable Textview.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="283dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="forgotPassword"
    android:text="Forgot your password?"
    android:textColor="#F0D9B3"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
```

^ here's my Textview code
and the activity i want to transition to is the ForgotPassword.class, how do i go about writing the intent code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an Intent in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578051/what-is-an-intent-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void forgotPassword(View view) {
    Intent in = new Intent(this, ForgotPassword.class);
    startActivity(in);

}
```