# How do I link 2 Pages in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have 2 actvities with a xml each but I don't know how to switch to the second page with a button.

Can someone send me the code for the MainActivitie.java please (for a button)

I currently use the findView and onClick

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start new activity on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Answer (score 1):

In your MainActivity use this code:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.java);
  startActivity(intent);
```

Please read about "Intents", I have added some links that will clear your concepts.
[Previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16183937/11747484)
[Intent Types](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-intent-tutorial)